# Forward USB/IP to physical USB OTG port

Tags: ipad, raspberry-pi, usb, usb-otg

I am currently trying to connect an iPad to a mac via the network, without using an existing software like virtualHere, USB network gate ... I came across USB/IP for Linux: http://usbip.sourceforge.net/. I because there is no OSX version, I thought about using two Raspberry Pi zeros to function as the USB host and client. Furthermore, I successfully attached the iPad, connected to Pi 1 via USB/IP to Pi 2:

```
#lsusb on Pi 2:
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:12ab Apple, Inc. iPad 4/Mini1
```

Now I want to link the USB Bus of the iPad (from USP/IP) to the physical USB port of the second pi, to then connect it via a micro USB cable to the mac.

```
iPad --USB--> PI 1 --Network(USB/IP)--> PI 2 --USB--> Mac
```

I know that the USB port is an OTG port and can be used as a host.
I tried socat, but It didn't worked:

```
sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/bus/usb/002/003 PTY,link=/dev/bus/usb/001/001
```

I guess I have to configure the OTG as a host first, but what mode should I use ?
This is a list of all OTG modes: https://gist.github.com/gbaman/50b6cca61dd1c3f88f41.
At the end, the mac should use the iPad, as "normally" plugged in via USB cable.

Please share some thoughts. Is it even possible to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to have the PTYs in raw mode to avoid echoing and CR/LF conversions etc.; and with some options you can see if data is transferred:

```
sudo socat -d -d -d -lu PTY,link=/dev/bus/usb/002/003,rawer,echo=0 PTY,link=/dev/bus/usb/001/001,rawer,echo=0
```